# Resizing window, resizing imaging towards center?

Tags: html, css

I was wondering if it's possible to resize an image or div with an image background, so it would go towards the center once the window size reaches the image size, and then when it goes further it will move from both the left and right to go towards the center:

For example:
[Ex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aoPgh.png)

From using 'margin: 0 auto' and other code I've found online, it looks like it aligns to the left and takes away the pixels from the right like:
[Ex2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvAQ9.png)

Comment: you want the image to shrink ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the `background-image` property, use the [`background-size: contain` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size).

HTML

```
<div id="background"></div>
```

CSS

```
#background {
     width: 100%;
     height: 50px;
     background: url("path/to/image.jpg") no-repeat center;
     background-size: contain;
}
```

Try and post more code than just screenshots in the future.